# Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A + A^T$ is positive (semi)definite, what is $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A + A^T$ is positive
>   (semi)definite, what is $A$?

or more generally, what are the properties on $A$ such that it holds true?

We see that if $A$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative diagonals, then it holds true. But is there a wider class of matrices such that this property holds?

Some thoughts:

$A + A^T$ PSD $\implies x^T (A + A^T) x \geq 0 \implies x^T Ax \geq x^T A^T x$...seems like we are not getting any where.

Comment: $A + A^T$ will be positive semidefinite if and only if $A = B + C$ for some (symmetric) positive semidefinite $B$ and skew-symmetric $C$ (i.e. $C^T = -C$).

Comment: Interestingly, the eigenvalues of such a matrix will necessarily have non-negative real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with this...

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1000 \\
-1000 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$